# AzureDevOps | GitHub, required status check

Tags: c#, github, xamarin, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I have setup AzureDevOps to build Xamarin mobile application, using GitHub (not Azure Repos yet).

In image below, Merge button is still clickable. I would like to disble it until build is completed successfully. I can not see any option to add WebHook for AzureDevOps to restrict branch protection rules via GitHub, all is managed via pipeline triggers from azure console

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by adding pipeline name in branch rules.